# How does rel="preload" influences window.onload?

Tags: javascript, html, window, onload, preload

How does the use of the rel="preload" directive influences the window.onload event? Lets say I have the following code:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
          window.onload = () => {
          console.log("page loaded")
          };
  </script>

  <link rel="preload" as="image" href="othersite.com/myimg.jpg" />
  <title>Website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Heading for the content below</h1>
  <p>Text text text</p>
  <img src="othersite.com/myimg.jpg" />
</body>

</html>
```

Is it possible that the onload event is fired before a resource, that is called using rel=preload, has been downloaded completely? So here the console will print "page loaded" before downloading the and showing the image myimg.jpg.

I read the following here: https://www.programmersought.com/article/5145872680/

> In addition, preload does not block the onload event of windows unless
> the request for the preload resource comes from a resource that will
> block the window load.

I'm not sure what it actually means though. Does that mean the onload event can be fired before a resource using rel=preload has been fully downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that the onload event is fired before a resource, that is called using rel=preload, has been downloaded completely?

Yes. Preload forces to make a request on priority **without** blocking window.onload(). So yes it can be fired [earlier](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/html-preload-prefetch).

For your second question, I feel the issue is of bad wording. I found one more statement on the internet having similar wording

> On top of that, preload does not block the window’s onload event, unless the resource is also requested by a resource that blocks that event.

This probably is refers this case:

Consider you have a URL font resource. One you are fetching using `preload`(**non-blocking**) and one you are fetching from a CSS stylesheet `<link>`(without any `preload/prefetch` directive, so **blocking**). If your CSS Stylesheet  is above the font `<link>`, then when the stylesheet was parsed it has already requested for the font URL and blocked the render. Second `<link>` with preload is of no point here.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  The thing is that I'm measuring the performance improvements of using preload  or not by looking at when the page onload event is triggered. Is this okay? Because of various reasons I cannot use another metric.

Comment: Obviously if all you care about is page load, then you can check this metric. Onload will trigger earlier than some stuff would have loaded, though. I guess you could always have a with and without preload speed test. Google Lighthouse gives all those metrics, if you can use it. To point out is preload really makes a difference when the stuff being preloaded will be discovered late by the browser. A font requested by a CSS file is only downloaded after the CSS file is downloaded. You can preload it. https://web.dev/preload-critical-assets/